# ASP.NET VB.NET - How to setup Single Sign On SSO using IIS7 Active Directory 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, single-sign-on

Problem: Every time I start a new session of Internet Explorer, the web application prompts me for my Active Directory Username and Password instead of automatically retrieving that information from the currently logged in Active Directory profile.

How do I setup Single Sign On in the web config or default.aspx.vb file code-behind so that it doesn't prompt me for my active directory credentials?

Here's the code from my web.config file:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true"/> 

   <authorization>

    <allow users="alg\bmccarthy, alg\phoward" />               
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_USER_ADMIN" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AMG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_BIG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GLA" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PIP" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PSM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_ANN" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_MWM" /> 
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GIM" />
    <deny users="*" />      
    </authorization>  

 </system.web>

 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
          <clear />
          <add value="Default.aspx" />
      </files>
  </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

    <endpoint address="http://acompwebservice.myagencyservices.com/aCompService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService1" contract="aComp_ServiceReference.IAcompService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService1" />
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I was looking at some [SSO code from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx) but I wasn't sure if I should Create a Login Token Method and I'm not using a database for logins because I'm using Windows Authentication w/ Active Directory. Is it possible to add something on the web.config to accomplish this?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified that the "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" option in IE is enabled?

In IE9, go to Tools, Internet Options, Security, Custom Level, User Authentication, Logon.

[image: Internet Options]

If you have selected "Automatic Logon only in Intranet Zone" and it still doesn't work, it means the website is not being displayed as an intranet website. You can have the website changed from being displayed as an internet website to an intranet website to get auto-login to work with this setting.

Alternatively, you can change the logon to "Automatic logon with current user name and password" which could potentially open up a security hole.

Alternatively, you could set up a Group Policy Object and add the website as a trusted site that will auto authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In IE9 under Security, Custom Level, User Authentication, Logon: I had Automatic Logon only in Intranet Zone and I changed it to Automatic logon with current user name and password. This did log me into the website without a username and password prompt. Does changing this cause any security issues?

Comment: You should revert that change and restrict Automatic logon only to the Intranet Zone. Once you have done that, add the url of the application to the Intranet Zone. this will preserve your security settings whilst applying the Intranet Zone settings to our application. I would also look into why that server was not detected as part of the local intranet zone?

Comment: the site doesn't load as an Intranet site and rather loads as an internet site which explains why it doesnt auto-authenticate. The Hardware Support guy says that this is because the website works with a web service. The web server guy will add the site as a trusted site w/ integrated security for the user groups that access acomp invitation so that the settings don’t  need to be changed manually for each user through a Group Policy Object Update.

Comment: @Brian McCarthy having your IT staff configure the site to be added as a trusted site through GPO is the most optimal solution.